# Reshape data causing memory error, Python 2.7. Code wrong?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, numpy, keras, reshape

Just like the title says, I'm trying to reshape 90k observations in Python2.7 for neural network input.

df is a dataframe with 90k rows. The column 'Embedded' has 1000 arrays of 100 floats, **in each row**. I need to reshape this column for a neural network input.

I can do it in batches of 10k rows, but 90k rows at once fails even on an AWS instance, is there a more efficient way?

```
z = df['Embedded']
z.shape 
(90000,) 

z = [np.array(a).reshape(1000,100) for a in z]
 ^^^^^ this is where failure occurs. I get "Memory Error"
```

**Please keep in mind, this code works for up to 10,000 rows of df['Embedded'] at a time. I just can't run the entire thing at once**

Comment: If there are lot of zeros involved, you might want to have a look at the sparse matrices. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html

Comment: Don't bother with sparse matrices unless you know your neural network accepts them.  But tell us about elements of `z`, i.e. the `a` that you try to reshape.  Things like `dtype` and shape.   I"m guessing the dataseries dtype is object, and the elements are already arrays.

Comment: dtype is 'O', type is numpy array, shape is (93882, )